# Is CyclicBarrier.getNumberWaiting() accurate?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, cyclicbarrier

I analysis the code in jdk1.8, but may have same issue in other jdk version

1. Let's assume the **parties = 3** in the following code

   CyclicBarrier cb = new CyclicBarrier(3);

[image]

parties = 3 and count > = 0, so the return value of **getNumberWaiting() <= 3**
but in some certain cases, **more than 3 threads** will be waiting
2.let's see the key code in CyclicBarrier

[image]

a) thread A in position 2 will return 0, now **there are 2 threads** await in position 3

b) after thread A execute lock.unlock(), thread B in position 1 get the lock(but the lock is unfair), so now index = 2, count =2, it will await in position 3, so now there are **3 threads await** in position 3

c) let's assume, the lock will always be got by the thread from position 1, so the number of waiting thread will be more and more

so the **getNumberWaiting() > 3** is the result

getNumberWaiting() = **(cyclic numbers) * parties - count**

Comment: Don't paste code as images. It makes it impossible to copy/paste for testing, and since it's text it doesn't need to be an image (I'm sure you can come up with a different indicator than a big red arrow to show where the error is).

Comment: Are you experiencing a bug, or are you claiming there's a bug based on eye analysis on a class that's been in the JDK since 1.5?

Comment: this is a bug discussion based on eye analysis, i just want to collect the supporters

Comment: @Kayaman this question is just the discussion and eye analysis, so i think paste code as image is appropriate

Comment: Then it's not a bug. Unless you can show code that results in buggy behaviour, it's only a matter of you not understanding why it works.

Comment: Not to mention that "Returns the number of parties currently waiting at the barrier. This method is primarily useful for debugging and assertions.".

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to look at the "generation" concept a little more. In your scenario, Thread A will have called `nextGeneration()` which resets all counts (getNumberWaiting() = 0) and signals all *current* waiters. Those waiters (on the now-previous generation) will shortly start completing.

So yes, there may be >3 threads against the `trip` Condition but 2 x old waiters have been signalled to leave and any new ones are awaiting a new signal. The `getNumberWaiting` is not computed using `Lock.getHoldCount()` so this is OK.

Comment: nextGeneration() will call trip.signalAll(), but this method can't make the thread leave until it get the lock, but we can assume that lock will always be grabbed in position 1, so the waiting threads will be accumulated in position 3

Comment: only the thread that is executed LockSupport.unpark() can continue or else it will always be blocked at position 3, trip.signalAll() can't unpark thread

Comment: Indeed an "old-waiter" may need to wait for a new one to sleep before it can compete but this is simply describing lock fairness. You're still saying the same thing as my answer. Number of waiters _on the internal lock_ can be >3 but `CyclicBarriers` contract remains intact because they of different generations.

Comment: so do you mean getNumberWaiting() = getNumberWaitOfCurrentGeneration(), getTotalNumberWaiting() = all threads that is waiting?

Comment: Exactly that. I don't think you should file a jdk bug!